# Limit Thumbnail Images on Product View Page

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

I am using Magento 2.4.1, I have added more than 3 images in the product but in the thumbnail, it only shows 3 thumbnails.
However, on clicking the Previous and Next buttons I am able to see all images.
I want to display all thumbnails of product images.

As shown in the below picture showing only 3 thumnails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the theme you are using, I checked Luma design just now on a product and it shows up to 7 gallery images under the main image.

[image]

Comment: I also think this may depends on the size of the photorama container.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using magneto default theme or third party theme.if you use third party theme than check theme configuration.if poosbile than share font-end and back end screenshot .

Comment: In custom theme some CSS was added to hide the thumbnails and to show only 3. .fotorama__nav-wrap--vertical .fotorama__nav__shaft .fotorama__nav__frame--thumb